# Unable to roll back display driver after updating it

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display-driver, display-adapter

My computer had slow loading on the welcome screen, so I looked up on the internet to find some ways to speed it up, because I felt like it's something unusual.

One of the top results said to Update the driver in the Device Manager.

I did that to my Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000, and suddenly, and to my shock, instead of updating to a better one (or saying that it is the highest possible it can get), it dropped down to Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

Now I'm trying to roll back the driver so it would return back, but the roll back button was greyed out like nothing was installed before it.

Now, since that the driver was messed up, after I rebooted, the screen resolution was lost, and I cannot change the brightness level.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Generally when I see this, I uninstall the current driver and then install the prior driver before restarting. You may need to turn OFF Other / Driver updates in Windows 10 update settings so it does not update again from the Microsoft Catalogue

Comment: See if there is a Windows restore point date just before the update, use that to restore it back.

Comment: @Moab Thank you for the help! I used the restore point that was created 2 days before this problem happened.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to fix this?

You should download the current driver for your display adapter from Intel.  Intel also has previous versions to their display driver.

- [Intel® Graphics Driver for Windows* [15.33]](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29473/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-?product=80939)

I also located the current Intel driver on Windows Update Catalog.

- [Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Intel%20Corporation%20driver%20update%20for%20Intel(R)%20HD%20Graphics%203000)

> Now I'm trying to roll back the driver so it would return back, but the roll back button was greyed out like nothing was installed before it.

This is due to the incorrect driver being installed.  **In your current configuration there isn't another basic adapter driver to rollback to.**

Comment: I tried installing the Intel(R) Graphics Driver before doing the System Restore process. It took a while, then a message appeared saying the driver was incompatible to my computer. Seems weird saying it's incompatible though it's the actual driver of the computer XD